# Узнать IP адрес клиента при поднятии сервера на c#?

Tags: c#, сервер, клиент-сервер

Мне нужно поднять сервер TcpListener + TcpClient, который на любой запрос отвечает отправляя сам IP клиента в ответе.

Какой функцией можно получить IP клиента?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);    
 TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

 Console.WriteLine ("client connected to " + IPAddress.Parse (((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString ()) + "on port number " + ((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Port.ToString ());
```

Я написал этот код читая MSDN, не тестировал.

TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient Method https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclient?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Sockets_TcpListener_AcceptTcpClient

TcpClient.Client Property https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.client?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Sockets_TcpClient_Client

Socket.RemoteEndPoint Property https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.remoteendpoint?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Sockets_Socket_RemoteEndPoint